# How to sum all long values without using BigInteger and overflow?

Tags: java, algorithm, integer-overflow

There are many long values, some are positive and some are negative, position and negative values exist at the same time and i have already know the sum of them will never orverflow.

How can i sum them without using BigInteger and get the right result?

I have tried to add a positve value and then a negative value so that each sum will not overflow.
But I will have to sort positive value and negative values into two groups, so I don't think it is a good solution, what if all the values are generated by a source like EventSourcing?

Comment: Provide example values. Keep in mind that a `long` data type can only hold a minimum value of `-9223372036854775808` (Long.MIN_VALUE) and a maximum value of `9223372036854775807` (Long.MAX_VALUE).

Comment: If you know the sum will not overflow, what happens if you just add the numbers, ignoring any overflow?

Comment: You don't need to sort positive values and negative values. You just need to [partition the array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) using 0 as the pivot. Then you need two indexes into the array, one for positive values, and the other for negative values. When the sum is positive, add a negative value. When the sum is negative, add a positive value. When you run out of either positive or negative values, you can safely add the rest of the unused values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is in Java, integer overflow has good mathematical properties, in particular: evaluating a sum with a `BigInteger` accumulator and then taking the lowest 64 bits of the result (ie converting it to a `long`), has the same result as working with a `long` the entire time, even if the sum sometimes overflows. That's a standard result from modular arithmetic.

That means that while you need to be careful to ensure that the result fits in a `long`, you already know that it will, so you can just let the sum overflow and you will still get the right result.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Harold's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75730509/1552534), the order of summing won't matter as long as the final sum fits in the designated type.

The following list of `ints` would certainly overflow at some point during the `int` summing process but the final sum would still fit in an int.   The long sum would clearly fit in a long with no overflow during the summing process.  But no matter how they are shuffled, the two sums are always the same.

```
List<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2, Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2,
                Integer.MAX_VALUE / 4, Integer.MIN_VALUE / 3,
                Integer.MIN_VALUE / 3, Integer.MIN_VALUE / 3));

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    int intSum = listInt.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    long longSum =listInt.stream().mapToLong(Long::valueOf).sum();
    if(intSum != longSum) {
        System.out.println("Problems with overflow.");
    }
    Collections.shuffle(listInt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try sorting them first. Then add the first and last elements, 2nd and 2nd last elements, and so on., and get a sum of those numbers.

Comment: Better way: Instead of adding pairs of (elm[0], elm[N]), elm([1], elm[N-1), etc - just check sign of accumulated result. If it is positive, add elm from begin of the array, if it is negative - add element from end of the array.

Comment: @olegarch I like your way of doing it as well :)